# Presto: how to extract items in a string to columns

Tags: presto, trino

I'm looking to use Presto to extract the filename and url from a string that looks like this. Any advice? Here's an example

{name=filename.pdf, url:https://url.com}

Thanks!

Comment: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/url.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`regexp_extract`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html?highlight=regexp_extract#regexp_extract):

```sql
WITH t(value) AS (
    VALUES '{name=filename.pdf, url:https://url.com}'
)
SELECT
    regexp_extract(value, 'name=(.*), url:(.*)}', 1) AS name,
    regexp_extract(value, 'name=(.*), url:(.*)}', 2) AS url
FROM t
```

=>

```
     name     |       url
--------------+-----------------
 filename.pdf | https://url.com
(1 row)
```

Comment: thank you. where does this go in the context of a larger 'select' statement

Comment: Look at the calls to `regexp_extract`. You'd place those wherever you need the value for the name or the url, accordingly.